# What is spsr_cxfs?

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

I'm looking at the code of U-Boot which grants the use of hypervisor mode and elevates the initial privilege to HYP mode. However, a mysterious register name bugs me while I try to understand the code.

From `arch/arm/cpu/armv7/nonsec_virt.S`:

```
1:
        mov     lr, ip
        mov     ip, #(F_BIT | I_BIT | A_BIT)    @ Set A, I and F
        tst     lr, #1                          @ Check for Thumb PC
        orrne   ip, ip, #T_BIT                  @ Set T if Thumb
        orr     ip, ip, r6                      @ Slot target mode in
        msr     spsr_cxfs, ip                   @ Set full SPSR
        movs    pc, lr                          @ ERET to non-secure
```

What is `spsr_cxfs`? I tried to Google it, but the results were the warning that I might be looking for results regarding SPSR_CX**SF**, and a bunch of assembly codes which are similarly coded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The register is SPSR; the rest just signifies which *parts* of it to update.

To summarise the definition in the Architecture Reference Manual, the operand to `msr` here is `SPSR_<fields>`, where `<fields>` "Is a sequence of one or more of" `c`, `x`, `s`, `f`, which represent bits 7:0, 15:8, 23:16 and 31:24 respectively.

What there isn't, though, is any specific mandate of a particular *order* to that sequence, so I'd expect any reasonable assembler not to care either.